# jquery on input y keyup no funcionan luego de respuesta ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy haciendo un buscador automático, el cual luego de escribir hace una espera de un par de segundos antes de hacer la búsqueda, **esto funciona perfectamente**, el problema es que luego de recibir la respuesta ajax, ya no puedo hacer ninguna búsqueda, los eventos ni siquiera retornan un log, simplemente no hace nada

esto es lo que he hecho

```
    function delay(callback, ms) {
        let timer = 0;
        return function () {
            let context = this, args = arguments;
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                callback.apply(context, args);
            }, ms || 0);
        };
    }

    $('#search_place_input').keyup(delay(function (e) {
        console.log('busqueda');
        searchPagination('places');
    }, 2000));
```

haciendo esto todo funciona correctamente, pero luego de la primer búsqueda, cuando quiero hacer otra, el no ocurre nada, ni siquiera el log muestra algún error

no sé si sirva de algo adjuntar la función encargada de hacer la consulta, la verdad no creo, pero es esta

```
    function pagination(type) {
        const dummy_url = new URL('{{ route("template.pagination") }}');

        dummy_url.searchParams.append('query', query);
        dummy_url.searchParams.append('key', type);
        dummy_url.searchParams.append('page', page.toString());
        dummy_url.searchParams.append('templateType', templateType);
        dummy_url.searchParams.append('language', $('#language').val());

        console.log(dummy_url);

        let base_pagination_url = '{{ route("template.pagination") }}' + dummy_url.search;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: base_pagination_url,
            success: function (data) {
                if (type.includes("places")) {
                    $('#places_container').html(data);
                    $('#search_place_input').val(query);
                    selectedPlace = UN_SELECT;
                }

                if (type.includes("templates")) {
                    $('#templates_container').html(data);
                    $('#search_template_input').val(query);
                    selectedTemplate = UN_SELECT;
                }
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                handleSessionExpired(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

luego de recibir su respuesta, ya no ocurre nada respecto al input, también intenté con esto pero el resultado es lo mismo, funciona solamente en la primer búsqueda

```
    $('#search_place_input').on('input', function (){
        console.log('input');
        searchPagination('places');
    });
```

Comment: `searchPagination`  es la  función `Pagination`supongo. Puedes  poner  el HTML. Y el  ordern en  que se ejecutan. Está muy disperso tu codigo y si ya  no se ejecutan es porque por alli se están cancelando.

Comment: Entre el   `on` y el `keyup`del mismo elemento invocas al  `searchPagination` que es asíncrono. No entiendo bien eso. cual se ejecutará primero.  Y en el ajax esta linea creo que lanza el evento òn`$('#search_place_input').val(query);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece una muy buena idea crear una función de retardo que puede ser usada para diferentes propósitos, evitando repetir código y solo hay que hacer unos pequeños cambios para que funcione como esperas.

***Lapsus brutus***: <s>La variable `timer` solo está disponible dentro de la función, por lo que no se pueden cancelar los temporizadores previos y las peticiones quedan encadenadas. Define esa variable fuera de la función, en contexto global.</s>

***Mea culpa***: No había puesto atención a la estructura de la función `delay()` y es correcta, se ejecuta en cuanto se asigna al evento, creando un contexto aparte y devolviendo la función anónima, que se ejecuta solo cuando el evento se dispara, por lo que la variable `timer` está disponible siempre en ese nuevo contexto.

Algunas recomendaciones para mejorar el funcionamiento y tratar de evitar errores:

- No retrases tanto la espera, en promedio, las teclas consecutivas toman entre 200 y 350 milisegundos, un tiempo mayor puede resultar en mala experiencia para el usuario, aunque en el fragmento de código con una espera de 500ms parece funcionar bien, pero debes tener en cuenta que la petición tomará un tiempo para obtener la respuesta
- Usa solo un evento, ya sea `keyup` o `input`; personalmente, prefiero el segundo, porque se dispara con cualquier modificación al campo, incluyendo copiar, cortar y pegar
- Ejecuta la función de búsqueda solo si hay algo para buscar y, de preferencia, que al menos se hayan tecleado dos caracteres, sin considerar espacios a los extremos: *" lugar "* debe ser solo *"lugar"*
- En la función, recibe el valor del campo, no sé si lo vas a usar en la variable `query` o en otra, pero debes incluirlo en la petición
- Para poder crear la URL correctamente, se debe incluir protocolo, dominio y ruta completos, si tu script es un archivo separado y no está siendo procesado por tu sistema de plantillas, entonces `{{ route("template.pagination") }}` no va a tener un valor adecuado, generando error

```js
function delay(callback, ms) {
    let timer = 0;
    return function () {
        let context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            callback.apply(context, args);
        }, ms || 500);
    };
}

// Escucha solo el evento input
$('#search_place_input').on('input', delay(function (e) {
    console.log('Buscar:', $(this).val());
    // Solo si hay algo para buscar y, de preferencia, al menos dos caracteres
    if($(this).val().trim().length >= 2) {
        // Incluye el valor a buscar
        searchPagination('places', $(this).val().trim());
    }
}, 500));

// Recibe el valor a buscar
function searchPagination(type, query) {
    console.log(type, query);
    // Asegúrate de que la URL es correcta, incluyendo protocolo
    const dummy_url = new URL('http://localhost/proyecto/buscar.php');

    dummy_url.searchParams.append('query', query);
    dummy_url.searchParams.append('key', type);

    console.log(dummy_url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search_place_input"><br>
```

Si esto no soluciona el problema, revisa la consola para ver si hay errores y, de ser el caso, edita tu pregunta para agregar los mensajes que aparecen.